# Are we allowed to install the Google Authenticator extension?

Tags: google-authenticator, authenticator

Since we need to use the google authenticator to login on WEX platforms, I would like to know if the following extension is approved for us to install in the browser instead of having the app in the phone.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/authenticator/bhghoamapcdpbohphigoooaddinpkbai

Comment: Approved by whom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whose approval you're trying to seek, IMHO, installing an authenticator on your browser is not a very good security practice. The whole point of having a Two-factor authentication system (or a Multi-factor authentication system) is to enhance security and make it difficult for anyone attempting to intrude into your secure logins. Having your Google authenticator in the browser (essentially in the same machine {desktop/laptop/tablet} as you usually login to) defeats that very purpose.

To put it more simply, enabling Two-factor authentication system using Google authenticator on your mobile phone would need an intruder access to both your machine and mobile to login whereas if you were to install the browser extension, the intruder can attempt to sneak in with access only to the machine.

Comment: Using a 2nd device is an often quoted application example of the 2FA, but not a necessity in most cases. It's called 2-factor-authentication, not 2-devices-authentication. ─ If you use a 2FA Browser PlugIn, you bind yourself to one exclusive machine, preventing people from other machines to login on your account, but also limiting yourself to this restriction. ─ Don't forget, your desktop computer is a unique device as well (even a virtual machine) and provides that required 2nd factor. ─ convenient, if it's the only machine where you need it; useless, if you need it somewhere else, too.

Comment: PS: I'm not arguing that an additional 2nd device wouldn't provide extra security. But it's not a requirement for 2FA.

Answer (score 1):

Since your desktop computer is a unique device (even a virtual machine) and provides that required 2nd factor, you can use a 2FA Browser PlugIn just as well.

You bind yourself to one exclusive machine. It will prevent people from other machines to login on your account from the internet. But you will also limit yourself to this restriction.

Convenient, if it's the only machine where you need it; useless, if you need it somewhere else, too.

You may argue about the security of the implementation of such plugins itself. But you may also have this argument about your phone's hardware, operating system and of course the 2FA app as well. The same goes for 2FA accounts, which can be used on multiple machines (and hacked), but still remains a 2nd factor.

Last but not least, nothing prevents you from logging into your account from your smartphone's browser, using the 2FA app on that very same smartphone.

A compromised machine is that one of many malicious scenarios, where it might get dangeraours. But then the attacker might just as well wait for you to perform the login.

Since it's called 2-factor-authentication, not 2-devices-authentication, a 2FA Browser PlugIn will fullfil that purpose. And if your security level needs don't require you to follow the [Truecrypt password length recommonendation of at least 20 random characters](https://www.truecrypt71a.com/documentation/security-requirements-and-precautions/choosing-passwords-and-keyfiles/#:%7E:text=A%20good%20password%20is%20a,crack%20using%20brute%2Dforce%20techniques.) you should be fine.

PS: I'm not arguing that an additional 2nd device wouldn't provide extra security. But it's not a requirement for 2FA.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Chrome extension is encrypted with discrete password and I've never heard of that security feature being breached. The only security vulnerabilities you will find on subject are from phony browser extensions.  Always download from Chrome Store.  Many organizations do not have MDM on mobile devices which makes this the more secure, manageable MFA solution in these cases.